# How to make pupeteer automatically follow redirects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

How could I make [pupeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) automatically follow the redirects, the same way the browser handles it?

For example, if I try loading a website `https://www.aonhewitt.com` on the browser, it automatically redirects to `https://www.aon.com/home/solutions/retirement.html`. But if I try the following with pupeteer:

```
const pageResponse = await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
```

It gives an error saying `"Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded"`. How could I avoid this error?

Comment: You can find a specific selector in the redirected page and mark it to that. Not an ideal solution but an easy quick fix.

Comment: You can try this `page
.waitForNavigation
([options])` as well.